# Breaking Ties Alphabetically Using Kruskal's Algorithm

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Kruskal's Algorithm picks the next edge simply by picking the lightest edge.  Doesn't that make breaking ties alphabetically impossible? If I had a graph where two edges `a -> b` and `a -> c` existed. If `a -> c` has a lighter edge weight, wouldn't Kruskal's Algorithm add the `a -> c` edge over the `a -> b` edge?

Maybe I am just confused on what breaking ties alphabetically means.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Doesn't it mean that if two or more edges have the *same* lightest weight, you should choose among them alphabetically?  That's what I understand “tie” to mean in this context.

Comment: Kruskal's algorithm doesn't rely on a particular ordering of the edges, so if two have equal weight, you can pick either one.

Comment: Okay, so breaking ties based on a certain parameter is only relevant if edge weights are equal; for Kruskal's that is.

Comment: So what exactly is your question, then? If Kruskal's algorithm produces a minimal spanning tree no matter how you break the tie, what are you asking?

Comment: MJD seems to have clarified what I was wondering. If a graph has all unique edge lengths, breaking tie alphabetically doesn't make any sense (because the shortest edge length will always be chosen).  However, in a situation where edge lengths are equal, the next node is chosen alphabetically.

Answer (score 2):

Kruskal's algorithm wants to add minimum-weight edges at each step (while avoiding circuits). "Ties" specifically mean the case where two edges have the same weight. In that case, we usually assume that the earlier alphabetically-identified edge is chosen.

This models the computational implementation that the vertices will necessarily be stored in some order in memory, and the standard find-lowest algorithm will record the earlier-encountered one as the minimal choice.